# MongoDB Project Date ranges in mongoDB based on month or Quarter

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Given a collection, I want to group ISODate by year and month and generate range of dates for each month.

For example if the dates are 10-10-2018, 11-10-2018, 11-10-2017, 04-04-2018
The output should be

```
{"ranges": [
    {"min": 01-10-2018, "max": 31-10-2018}, 
    {"min": 01-10-2017, "max": 31-10-2017}, 
    {"min": 01-04-2018, "max": 31-04-2018}, 
]}
```

I could project month and year separately and group them and arrive at

```
[Oct 2018, Oct 2017....]
```

Is there a way to arrive at the above output using mongo aggregate query

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/#exp._S_dateToString, then https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/ if you know ranges or https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/ if you don't.

Comment: None of the above. would work. My question is specifically to generate start and end date of a month given a month and year

Comment: Use the first link. Start of the month is "%Y-%m-01" End of the month is beginning of next month - 1 day, then "%Y-%m-%d" of the result.

Comment: Nice idea thanks. Will try and get back